# Defining which project should be deployed to an Azure Functions app from source control

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

We have a collection of Azure Function Apps in c# net core. Each App contains a small number of Azure Functions. All Function Apps reside in a single git repository.

We would like some of our environments to deploy automatically from source (e.g. bitBucket or gitHub).

How do we configure the project so that Azure knows which project in source relates to which created Function App?

I have searched around this problem for a number of days and have not seen any results that sit outside of "it just works" so can only assume that we are missing something fundamental.

Comment: there are several ways to deploy function apps ? Which one are you looking for ?

Comment: Apologies, that could have been clearer. By "From Source" I mean from one of the git repository integrations.

Comment: you can create a repo per function app ? Also which language are you using ? C#, nodejs, python, java, others ?

Comment: C# added to question cheers

Comment: Ahem, my answer will do what you're after... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/devops/) (formerly VSTS) to deploy to Azure, you use YAML to define a build pipeline which can publish an artifact from each of your function apps. The artifacts then get picked up by a release pipeline and can be deployed to Azure.

The basic building blocks of this are, firstly some YAML like this in your build pipeline for each project:

```
...

steps:
# a script task that let's you use any CLI available on the DevOps build agent, also uses a variable for the build config
- script: dotnet build MyFirstProjectWithinSolution\MyFirstProject.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build MyFirstProject'

# other steps removed, e.g. run and publish tests

- script: dotnet publish MyFirstProjectWithinSolution\MyFirstProject.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output MyFirstArtifact
  displayName: 'dotnet publish MyFirstProject'

# a DevOps named task called CopyFiles (which is version 2 = @2), DevOps supplies lots of standard tasks you can make use of
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: 'MyFirstProjectWithinSolution\MyFirstArtifact\**'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

# now publish the artifact which makes it available to the release pipeline, doing so into a sub folder allows multiple artifacts to be dealt with
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish MyFirstArtifact artifact'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\MyFirstProjectWithinSolution\MyFirstArtifact'
    artifactName: MyFirstArtifact

# now repeat the above for every project you need to deploy, each in their own artifact sub-folder
```

Next you create a release, which in its simplest form picks up the artifacts and does one or more deployment, here's a simple one which deploys two function app projects:

[image: Simple Release Pipeline]

Within a deployment stage (right hand side above), you can define your release process, again in its simplest form you can just deploy straight to production or to a slot, although until function slots are out of preview you could also spin up another function app and deploy and test there.

This screenshot shows a simple deployment which uses a standard Azure Function App deployment from Azure DevOps:

[image: Deployment Tasks]

Within your deployment stage you can define which artifact is deployed and after running your build pipeline for the first time you'll get to see all the available artifacts that it created.

All or parts of the above can be automated from pushing a branch (or other triggers such as on a schedule). Notifications and "gates" can be added as well if you want manual intervention before release or between release stages.

There are also other ways to cut this up, eg with multiple build pipelines, it’s basically completely flexible but the above are the elements you can use to deploy one or more function apps at a time.